# @react-google-maps/api with Typescript - InfoBox issue - type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => number'

Tags: react-typescript

I am using `@react-google-maps/api` with Typescript. Everything runs fine so far, however I have hit a problem (that I had not before I moved the project to Typescript).

This is my code (note that I have added the @ts-expect-error to try to push Typescript suppress this message, however it does not seem to be working in this case.

```
<InfoBox
  // @ts-expect-error
  className={classnames('info-box', { 'visible': selectedMarker === 
  checkpoint.checkpoint_id })}
  position={{
    lat: checkpoint.lat,
    lng: checkpoint.lng
  }}
  options={{ closeBoxURL: ``, enableEventPropagation: true,
  pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(-16, -110) }}
>
```

I am getting following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: InfoBoxProps, context: any): InfoBoxComponent', gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: InfoBoxProps, context: any): InfoBoxComponent', gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => number'.ts(2769)
```

I tried to Google out the error code or `Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => number'` but could not see any such result.

I would like to understand what does this error mean and naturally fix this for Typescript to be ok with it (It worked fine before I moved the file over to Typescript).

It is strange that the error suppression does not work in this case, while it works in other cases.

Anyway, thank you for your kind help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It can help you

`<InfoBox position={new google.maps.LatLng(yourPosition)}/>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).